# How to set the location of a button anywhere in your JFrame

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

What I want to do is put the button down the bottom left of the application. Could somebody just give me an example of how to do it?

This is what I have:

[image: application image]

Here's my code:

```
        super("Test");

    /**Create Components**/
    JPanel addPanel = new JPanel();
    JButton addButton= new JButton("Add");

    /**Add Components**/
    addPanel.add(addButton);
    this.add(addPanel);

    /**Set Components Properties**/
    addButton.setLocation(12, 371);
    addButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(116, 40));
    addPanel.setLocation(12, 371);
    addPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(116, 40));

    /**Frame Properties**/
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(dimension1, dimension2));
    this.setResizable(false);   
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: I'm assuming your long term goal isn't one frame with one button. Therefore, you need to research "layout managers" for Java. Try, for example, [MiG Layout](http://www.miglayout.com/), which is great for forms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try **BorderLayout**

```
addPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
addPanel.add(addButton,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Even inside you addPanel you can have another panel(say bottomLeft) with **Grid Layout**

```
bottomLeft.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3,200,0));
bottomLeft.add(addPanel)
```

Comment: I think you should give him an-example to get the accepted answer:)

Comment: Sorry No offense but I believe if you spoon feed someone he will never learn it the right way :)

Answer (score 9):

Firstly set the frame's layout to `null` if you are using JFrame, or set layout's panel to `null` if you are using panel,then use `setBounds()` method :

```
button.setBounds(x,y,width,height);
```

See this example I made for you :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class ButtonLocationDemo extends JFrame{

 private JButton button;
 public ButtonLocationDemo(){
      JPanel p = new JPanel();
      button = new JButton("Button");
      p.setLayout(null);
      button.setBounds(40,100,100,60);
      p.add(button);

      getContentPane().add(p);
      //setLayout(null);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
      setSize(400,400);
      setVisible(true);

     }
   public static void main(String...args){
       new ButtonLocationDemo();
       }
}
```

Comment: Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  For a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or combinations of them, along with layout padding & borders for white space, to organize the components.

Comment: user2413200: Please give the accepted answert to `@Aniket Thakur`'s answer

Comment: Hey i did this and it worked but then i tried doing the same thing to add another button next to it and it makes the old button disapear.

Comment: That's probably because you are not giving it a new location, you must change x,y every time adding a new component.